Ctrl+Space on Kubuntu 24.04
On Kubuntu 24.04 the shortcut Ctrl+Space is associated with changing the keyboard layout, but I need to use that shortcut in all IDE's that I use (Intellij, Visual Studio).
How can I remove the system from using Ctrl+Space?

It is ibus which is changing the keyboard layout when you run ctrl + space?

In System Settings -> Regional Settings -> Input Method -> Configure global options
just remove the ctrl+space Trigger Input Method Hotkey

Thank you. This fixed it.
